# Unable to compare database schema using SSDT Visual studio 2012 "Unable to determine the database platform type. The database may be unavailable.."

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have created database project in Visual studio 2012 Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3. 
I am using this database project for comparing and publishing database on SQL Server 2008 R2 Version 10.50.4000.0

My database project target platform was set to SQL Server 2008.

My SSDT version is 11.1.20627.00

Now my SQL Server version upgraded to SQL Sever 2012 Version 12.0.2000.8

After that i changed my database project target platform to SQL Server 2012.

But it is not allowing me to compare database schema or publish database.

It throws following error

**Error 345 Validation error in the target: *DB_Name* Unable to determine the database platform type.  The database may be unavailable..**

I have also checked from Edit Connection wizard using Test Connection button that database connection is successful.

Can anybody please help me on this?
Is there any more configuration i need to set for changing database platform type?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Version 12.0.2000.8 of SQL Server actually means you're on SQL Server 2014. It's confusing but SQL Server 2012 == Version 11, SQL Server 2014 == Version 12.

To resolve this, please update the SQL Server tooling in Visual Studio 2012 to be SQL Server 2014 compatible per the [instructions here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/jj650015). For VS2012 the SQL Server updates aren't built-in, happily from VS2013 onwards the updates show up automatically through the Visual Studio update mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After installing SSDT compatible tool for 2014 it worked for me. And yes i got confused with version that you mentioned. It is indeed SQL Server 2014 that i installed. Once again thanks a ton.. :)

Comment: I noticed that after updating, SSDT forced me to migrate my database project file within Visual Studio. Presumably, this means I would have to upgrade my TFS build environments also?

Comment: @Rabid It's recommended but should not be required unless you are targeting SQL 2014. What happened was your project file version was updated but in a way that's still backwards compatible.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm. My database project still builds fine through TFS. Phew :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

SQL server version unmatched
Update VS with SQL Tooling extension [How to update extension](http://www.asptricks.net/2015/07/database-schema-compare-error-in-visual.html)

Answer (score 0):

Database schema compare error in visual studio 2013
Message: Unable to determine platform type.

Full Error: Validation error in the source: db_name : Unable to determine the database platform type. The database may be unavailable.. SqlSchemaCompare1 0 0

Causes:  SQL server unmatched.

Solution: SSDT updates for visual studio. So go to Tools, Extension and updates..
[Reference](http://www.asptricks.net/2015/07/database-schema-compare-error-in-visual.html)